# Properties file as simple as in Java?

Tags: c#, properties, resources, key-value

I am looking for a simple way to use values written in my *properties.resx* file in C#. In Java, this is really simple since you have a file *.properties*.
I need such file to write my constant strings inside as if I want to change a constant, I just have to change it in that file. Anyone has an example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET we typically don't use a resx file to store settings like you describe, we use a settings class. Go to the properties for your project and click on the Settings tab. Create your settings there and they'll be written to the app.config/web.config where they can be overridden. You can then access the values using `Settings.Default.NameOfSetting`.

Comment: Do you know why when I specify that a property is of INT type, it generates me a string type property ?

Comment: It doesn't. If you select `int` in the "Type" dropdown it's an int. You can write `int foo = Settings.Default.MySetting` and it works just fine.

Comment: So it has to be an error from my visual studio because it's not working. Will try to get this done ! Thanks for all !

Comment: Unfortunately "it's not working" isn't really enough detail for me to even begin to suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: As I told you, when I write a property in the properties file of my project, even if I specify that the property is an INT thanks to the select box, it overrides me the property in file app.config file as a string. So the only solution that I found is to convert the value after accessing it.